# How do I combine one static string and a variable name to make one variable name which is defined?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In my batch file, I have some lines:

```
set "line1=bla"
set "line2=what"
```

I want to know how to put a variable onto the end of a static string to equal a defined variable name.
So, `canum` is the line number.
The variable `%line1%` exists, but in order to loop the above code above so I could have as many lines as I wanted written into a file, I would have the line number as a variable that increases every time it loops, then checks if the variable combined with `line` exists. It's hard to explain.

So basically, I would start out with some variables that, well vary in being defined or not. `line1` could be defined, but could not. I would want to have one variable that is a number that increases by one every time the batch file loops that acts as the `1` in `line1` or the `2` in `line2`. That number increases every time the batch file loops. First, the batch file checks if the nth line is defined, and if it is, to echo it into a file as an additional line using `echo %lineNUM%>>file.txt` (with NUM being the nth number). However, I don't know how to combine one static string (which, in my case is `test` and a variable (which, in my case is `%canum%`) to make one variable name that is defined.

```
:writeloop_setuplogical
set /a canum = %canum% + 1
if NOT defined !line%canum%! :done
echo !line%canum%!>>file.txt
```

This is my best take of what I just tried to explain.
This makes my brain hurt.

Comment: [Arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points: ditch the self reference in the set /A, all you need is `Set /A canum+=1`.  Accessing arrays in batch requires the index variable to be expanded with delayed expansion within code blocks (parentheses). For /L loops are used to do this, as the 'combined' variable is able to be expanded with the for loops variable - `!expansion [%%i]!`

To prevent erroneous output, Redirection syntax should really be:

```
>>File.txt Echo !Line%Canum%!
```

Conditional testing can be used to ensure only variables containing defined values are appended to the file.

```
If Not "!Line%Canum%!" == "" >>File.txt Echo !Line%Canum%!
```

To execute within a code block:

- Current value

  `For %%i in (!Canum!) Do If Not "!Line%%i!" == "" >>File.txt Echo !Line%%i!`
- All values

  `For /L %%i in (1,1,!Canum!) Do If Not "!Line%%i!" == "" >>File.txt Echo !Line%%i!`